# Spatial derivative of a velocity vector

Tags: vector-analysis

Suppose there is a velocity field $\vec{V}=V_r(r,\theta) ~\hat{r}+V_\theta(r,\theta) ~\hat{\theta}$, where $V_r$ is the radial velocity component and $V_\theta$ is the azimuthal velocity component. The polar coordinate system is defined in the conventional manner i.e., $x = r ~cos(\theta)$ and $y = r ~sin(\theta)$.

It is possible to obtain the derivative of a particular velocity component such as $\frac{\partial V_r}{\partial r}$, $\frac{\partial V_r}{\partial \theta}$, $\frac{\partial V_r}{\partial x}$, or $\frac{\partial V_r}{\partial y}$. Would these terms be considered scalar fields or vector fields? How is the directionality encoded?

Comment: $(r,\theta) \mapsto V_r(r,\theta)$ is a $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ function. Partial derivatives of $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ functions are $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ functions. Hence $$(r,\theta) \mapsto V_r(r,\theta)$$$$(r,\theta) \mapsto \frac{\partial V_r(r,\theta)}{\partial r}$$$$(r,\theta) \mapsto \frac{\partial V_r(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta}$$$$(r,\theta) \mapsto \frac{\partial V_r(r,\theta)}{\partial x}$$$$(r,\theta) \mapsto \frac{\partial V_r(r,\theta)}{\partial y}$$ are all $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ functions (aka scalar fields because the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: This is a fantastic write-up, thank you. Just to clarify, taking the derivative of the entire velocity field $\frac{\partial \vec{V} }{\partial x} = \frac{\partial V_r}{\partial x} \hat{r} + \frac{\partial V_\theta}{\partial x} \hat{\theta}$ would be a vector field as it would be a $R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ function?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I am not very familiar with taking partial derivative of vector field but according to the definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_function#Partial_derivative, your argument looks good to me.